# ML Flow autolog with catboost

Tags: databricks, mlflow

I am trying to use auto logging of ML Flow with catboost - but looking at the UI of the experiment (in Databricks UI) I don't see any parameters or metrics logged.

My code is:

````
mlflow.sklearn.autolog()
model_for_analytics = catboost.CatBoostRegressor(**cb_params)
model_for_analytics.fit(x_train, y_train, **cb_fit_params)```
````

Comment: This is the first time you are looking to leverage mlflow's autologging for catboost model right?

Comment: Currently its still in the weeds(might be ), already raised before
https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/6073
Without autolog was implemented a while back
https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/2769
https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/pull/2417/files

Comment: @teedak8s it is indeed my first time.  I was looking at the documentation of autologging at https://docs.databricks.com/applications/mlflow/databricks-autologging.html#supported-environments-and-frameworks and it listed scikit-learn - hence I was expecting the  support. Perhaps they should indicate per framework which model types are supported.